# .Net Split with split characters retained

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# split string but keep split chars / separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators)

Is there a simple way to do a .Net string split() function that will leave the original split characters in the results?

Such that:

```
"some text {that|or} another".Split('{','|','}');
```

would result in an array with:

```
[0] = "some text "
[1] = "{"
[2] = "that"
[3] = "|"
...
```

Preferably without a regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484919/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-strings-and-include-the-delimiters-using-net @TimSchmelter not all of those answers are regex implementations.

Comment: good solutions at that link.. thx

Answer (score 3):

check out **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484919/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-strings-and-include-the-delimiters-using-net)**

the first answer with a RegEx solution, the second for a non-regex solution...

In Concept...

```
string source = "123xx456yy789";
foreach (string delimiter in delimiters)
    source = source.Replace(delimiter, ";" + delimiter + ";");
string[] parts = source.Split(';');
```

Comment: I got downvoted for this very answer. you a lucky guy!

Comment: @Devtron: Link only answers are discouraged, even if they link to stackoverflow. This one goes on to provide an example as well. (Just guessing by the way)

Comment: @Guvante mine had a better example, further down in the answer list :)

Comment: @Devtron but much more complicated....

Comment: but this does not work for ";" characters. it may not be very complicated, but it has an obvious bug.

Comment: just "in concept". you could replace ';' with '^' depending on what data you allow your string

Comment: accepts all input? make it something crazy big like '!@#%#$@#$#@' lol, that will never get hit by accident.

Comment: hey, now youre talking! btw, I upvoted this, even though I got hated on.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably roll your own using [String.IndexOf Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) to find all of your initial separator characters, and merge those in with the results of `String.Split`